# How to implement tabs on iOS at the top that are swipe-able?

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

I'm developing an iOS app and I was wondering how to implement a design element. I've looked but there isn't a answer that I was completely looking for. Any help would be great. :)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the functionality in more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to build it from the scratch, then maybe you can take a look at this- https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu

Comment: Thank You! This was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @TechSd then you should upvote and accept this answer